# My js for loop stop after 0?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, for-loop, break

I write some js code to loop through the html document and my loop just **stop after 0 [which is the start of the loop]**

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
    if (jsBox >= 0) {
        for (i=jsBox;i<documentContent.length;i++) {
            if (documentContent[i] == '[') {
                startJs = i;
                console.log(startJs);
                break;
            }
        };
    } else {
        console.log('Note: no js container found');
    }

    //find end of css
    for (i=startJs;i<documentContent.length;i++) {
        if (documentContent[i] == ']') {
            endJs = i;
            console.log(endJs);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it something to do with the code inside the code? Does`break;` statement in the inner loop also break the outer loop, if so, how can I only break out of one loop?
-Thanks

Comment: well, is the value of jsBox >= 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it something to do with the code inside the code?

Yes.

> Does `break;` statement in the inner loop also break the outer loop

No. But the inner loop does modify the counter variable of the outer loop. You should use a different variable name, and also [local variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

```
// assuming already declared: jsBox, documentContent, startJs, endJs
for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    if (jsBox >= 0) {
        for (var j=jsBox; j<documentContent.length; j++) {
            if (documentContent[j] == '[') {
                startJs = j;
                console.log(startJs);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Note: no js container found');
    }

    //find end of css
    for (var j=startJs; j<documentContent.length; j++) {
        if (documentContent[j] == ']') {
            endJs = j;
            console.log(endJs);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, older IE does not support bracket notation for character access on strings. And you'd be much better off using the simple [`indexOf` String method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) than those loops:

```
var startJs = documentContent.indexOf('[', jsBox),
    endJs = documentContent.indexof(']', startJs);
```

Comment: Thanks, what does the second parameter for jsBox of `indexOf('[',jsBox)?`

Comment: And how can you get the position of the `'['` if you use indexOf?

Comment: Read the docs I've linked! The second argument lets you specify the start (if you don't want to search from the beginning) and the found position is the return value

Answer (score 1):

You are making wrong variable reuse here. You reuse **i** in both the inner loops, resetting its starting value and then incrementing it till it reaches **documentContent.length** (which is probably bigger than 10).Then the outter loop statement will be found false (the value of **i** has changed in the inner loops) and you will be exited from it.
 I suggest that you use different variable(s) in the inner loops, so that you do not have the outter loop affected.(Although the last inner loop sets the last value of **i** before the outter statement check here, it is wrong to be reused in any of these loops and has to be changed in **both** of them).